# Matlab scatter not working

Tags: java, matlab, scatter-plot

Matlab `scatter` is not plotting data and returns a `NaN` figure handle.  This is on Windows 8, Matlab R2013b.  `plot` works just fine.  And I mean it literally--

```
>> figure; scatter(rand(100,1), rand(100,1))
```

gives

```
ans =

   NaN
```

and an empty figure.  Examples from the Matlab scatter help page do the same thing.  This is a recent happening so it is related to Java or Windows updates somehow?  It has persisted through a reboot of the computer.  I have

```
>> version -java

ans =

Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

Comment: Do you have a variable or function called `scatter` in your workspace?

Comment: @David Hah!  Not strictly speaking, but I have a class member named scatter that has become exposed after `@myclass` got turned into `Copy of @myclass` by Windows.  If you want to make an answer out of your comment I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think you should answer, with some details of how you found and fixed it, I have no idea about classes! My comment was just the generic response for first check for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was hiding Matlab's `scatter` function with my own version, which I had created for a class `myclass`.  The error was subtle--in copying my files to a new machine, Windows at some point generated a copy of my class folder, `@myclass`, which it named `Copy of @myclass`.  In searching the path for functions, Matlab knows to ignore any folder name which begins with '@'.  But `Copy of @myclass` no longer begins this way, and therefore its definition of `scatter` was exposed.

This issue was revealed using Matlab's `which` command, i.e.

```
>> which scatter
```

As @DavidHahl points out, you can get this error also by having a variable named `scatter` in the workplace, which is conceptually similar to what in fact had happened.